# how to smoothly move object on ellipse shape view

Tags: objective-c, uiview

Consider this image

[image]

How would I go about drawing a custom `UIView` that is literally just a ellipse. Would I just override the `drawRect` method? And can someone show me the code for dragging red ball on ecllips path?

Comment: Drawing the eclipse is one problem.  Drawing the red ball is another problem.  Making the red ball respond to user touch in order to be dragged around is a third problem.  I recommend [solving one problem at a time](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/).

Answer (score 1):

Drawing the ball can be done in a custom `drawRect` if you want, or you could use `CAShapeLayer`:

```
UIView *ball = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
ball.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

CAShapeLayer *ballLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
ballLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(50, 50) radius:48 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI * 2.0 clockwise:YES].CGPath;
ballLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
ballLayer.lineWidth = 0.5;
ballLayer.fillColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
ballLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
ballLayer.shadowRadius = 2;
ballLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.75;
ballLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
[ball.layer addSublayer:ballLayer];

[self.view addSubview:ball];
```

Creating the ellipse could be done in a similar fashion.

Dragging the ball could be done with a gesture.

```
UIGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[ball addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

Where:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    CGPoint translate = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        gesture.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(translate.x, translate.y);
    } else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        gesture.view.center = CGPointMake(gesture.view.center.x + translate.x, gesture.view.center.y + translate.y);
        gesture.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
}
```

You presumably would want to constrain the ball's movement to the ellipse, then you'd just adjust the `translate` coordinates accordingly. But hopefully this illustrates how to create a gesture recognizer, and move a `UIView` accordingly.